# Redirect if resource not found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a Node.JS app running, and for various reasons, occasionally a page will request a resource that doesn't exist; typically, an image.

In these cases, or generally any 404, I'd like to serve a dynamic resource in it's place. Typically this just involves turning a relative path into an absolute one.

For example, an image is requested by asking for `/images/whatever.png`. I'd like to return the resource located at `http://www.whatever.com/images/whatever.png`.

How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: How are you serving up static resources now? You'd have to hook into that, and check if the resource exists, if not redirect to something else. As a sidenote, you could do this clientside using the `onerror` handler for when the image fails to load.

Comment: With the standard Express static resources middleware.